# python showing too many digits after decimal separator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried :

`x = 3.4`

`print(x - math.floor(x))`

In both in console and Jupyter Notebook, the result shows `0.3999999999999999`
but why not just `0.4` as the result.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your question `Why is this happening?` or `How do I get it to be 0.4`?

Comment: @Algebra8, it is `Why is this happening`

Answer (score 1):

It is actually not due to python but is inherent to how floats are implemented and would also happen in javascript for instance.

This explanation should answer your question: https://floating-point-gui.de/basic/

If you need to handle it as a decimal, as pointed out you should check the `decimal` module, or you could round the final result before rendering.

Answer (score 0):

To get `0.4` you can use the `decimal` module:

```
>>> import decimal 
>>> x = decimal.Decimal('3.4')
>>> print(x - math.floor(x))
Decimal('0.4')
```